# Download Image from URL & Post to API via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

There are a number of images that I'm displaying on our website. In addition, we allow users to upload images or preview images from an external source URL. All images on the site are available via standard `<img>` tags, where the `src` is set to the relevant image URL.

When an image is clicked, I'd like to take the image and post it to an API, which will then process the image and return a result:

**Base64 Encode**:

```
function getBase64Image(img) {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg|jpeg);base64,/, "");
}
```

**AJAX**

```
$("#img").click(function () {

  var base64 = getBase64Image(document.getElementById("img"));

  $.ajax({
    url: post_url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: { "img_data": base64 },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function () {
    ...
    },
  });
});
```

There are a couple of issues that I'm aware of and probably more. I'm not technically "uploading" an image, because most of the images are already being displayed on the page. I'm also encoding in Base64 to send to the server, but I really need the data decoded in UTF-8. I suppose that I can do that server-side, but would be nice to have it done here.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this scenario you should have two flows: one to the image the user upload, and one to the image from external resource.

In the flow to the images from external resource: your system knows the external URL to the images, so you can pass the URL in the post request, then in the server you download the image and manipulate it as you want.

And the flow to the image selected by the user, you post the file to the server and manipulate it as you want.